# If $A\leq \mathbb{Z}$ then $\sup A\in A$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to prove the above statement for A which is an upper bounded subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Here's what I did:

*From the axiom of completness we deduct that the supremum of A exists.*

*Let $\sup A=a$*

*Then by definition of supremum: $\exists \varepsilon>0 : a-\varepsilon<x, x\in A $.*

*Let $ε=1$ then $a-1<x$.*

*We suppose that $a$ doesn't belong to $A$. Then $x<a$. So in case $\sup A$ doesn't belong to $A$, $a-1<x<a\Rightarrow 0<x<1$ which is a contradiction because $x\in A\leq \mathbb{Z}$*

**I think this is a good enough proof, however my textbook goes on like this:**

*$a-1<x<a$. We find $y\in A$ such that: $a-1<x<y<a\Rightarrow 0<y-x<1$ which is a contradiction because both $x,y$ belong to $A$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$*

I have two questions. Is my proof not enough? And secondly how does he goes from $a-1<x<y<a$ to $0<y-x<1$

Comment: By $A\leq \mathbb{Z}$ do you mean $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: In general you can not deduce the existence of a supremum. What about the case $A=\mathbb{Z}$?!

Comment: A is an upper bounded non empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ so I guess $A<\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Even then that is not enough (to say $A \subset \mathbb{Z}$).  What about $A = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, \ldots\}$?

Comment: A is bounded from above so it can't be $A={2,4,6,8,10,..}$

Comment: I know. I'm commenting on the notation in your hypothesis.  Saying $A < \mathbb{Z}$ allows things that aren't bounded above (like the evens).  If you want to assume it's bounded above, you have to say it.